# Update iOS application silently (programmatically)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing application for in-house distribution (so there can't be rejection from Apple).

As I'll distribute my app using Enterprise distribution, I'm missing one of key features of AppStore - Auto/Manual updates. (*I know, that I can show popup users to update application*)

Also I know, that application can download dynamic framework with code, and also can download bundle with resources.

So my question: How can I download storyboard (compiled to nib) from remote host, and load it into project?

Or is there anyway to make something like ***Sparkle.framework*** on OSX, which will update all the bundle of my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can't update it silently and automatically but you can ditribuite with TestFlight or similar services. Crashlytics present an alert to update if a new version is available (and then use itms-services) .
You can even use itms-services yourself and build your own distribution system if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Artisan](http://useartisan.com/). They allow you to build portions of your app on their web interface and dynamically swap out views and workflow. It is generally used for A/B testing but could be used for your purposes too. This way you could change significant elements of your app without needing people to update anything. You can even setup different views for different groups of people, and again, all after application launch.

It is also free for <10,000 users, which I am assuming would not be an issue for an enterprise application.